# google app engine apps not allowed to make request to craigslist

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am parsing a rss from a website in php

> $url = 'http://seattle.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=furniture&s=0&format=rss';
>   $result = file_get_contents($url);

This works fine locally, but after deploy to GAE, the $result returns just newlines. `\r\n`

I also set libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) on top of the script.

Edit:
I found the problem. Craigslist is blocking google app engine apps. Once I switched to "http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/sportsheadlines" it works. But the exact same code does not work for "http://seattle.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=furniture&s=0&format=rss".
I could be wrong, I would appreciate if anyone could tell me more about it. thanks.

Comment: libxml_disable_entity_loader — Disable the ability to load external entities. Be mindful that this also disables url loading.

Comment: Not fluent with PHP, and not exactly sure why this isn't working, but there's a bunch of differences with the URLFetch example on the official App Engine site. I'd recommend you take a look.

Link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

Comment: Have you tried adding the "http://" prefix to $url?

Comment: yes, I have the prefix http:// prefix to the url. I think I found the problem, it is craigslist blocking google app engine apps. Once I switched the url to some other rss (abc news feed) , it works.

Answer (score 1):

Craigslist 404s requests from AppEngine for whatever reason.  If I switch the user agent in the devel env to  something other than AppEngine, it works file.